# Angular2 - Don't want angular router to see path separators as separate route segments

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route as below:

`path: 'Foo/:Address'`

The Address parameter can contain string as below:

`boo/bar/a` or 
`boo/b`

But when my code routes to any of the above address, I get an exception that there are no matching routes. I suppose it considers `foo`, `bar` and `a` to be different route segments and hence it throws an exception. I need a single param in the route as the number of segments are random and the url should be as it is without any string replacement.

Is there any way I can let angular know that anything after `foo` is a single param?

I am using below versions:

`"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4"`

`"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1"`

Comment: Write it as a query string, path: 'Foo?address=:param'

Comment: @shammelburg  not an option.. I want it as it is in the url.

Comment: Does "a" in "boo/bar/a" represent the address param?

Comment: @shammelburg yes it does..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you configure your routes like this:

```
{
    path: 'address', children: [
        { path: '**', component: YourComponent }
    ]
}
```

Then:

**OPTION 1:** Fetch individual parts in your component using :

```
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let addr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < route.snapshot.url.length; i++)
        addr += (addr !== '' ? '/' : '') + route.snapshot.url[i];

    console.log('full address', addr);
}
```

**OPTION 2:** Grab the URL from the router (after NavigationEnd) in your component using:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(x => {
        if (x instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            console.log(this.router.url);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a similar setup now. But then the number of segments are not fixed, so it is not feasible to add that much routes.

Comment: Updated my answer again to add a little bit more info :)

Comment: But then the address param would not have the complete address. For e.g if the address is `boo/bar/a` then the address param will only have `boo`

Comment: This can work but I am looking for something like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8049) so that there is no dependency on the address string.

Comment: The url does not change on the address bar for this solution.

Comment: are you talking about using a querystring in place of address params?  if that's the case - wont the querystring change in the address bar instead of the base url?

Comment: no not the query string. the route url itself remains same.